# CLAuthorizationStatus returning kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined despite being authorised

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

I'm having some bother with an authorisation state here I'm not certain what's going on.

```
 if(sender.on == TRUE)
{
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];

    CLAuthorizationStatus authStatus = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
    bool headingStatus = [CLLocationManager headingAvailable];

    if( !(authStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized))
    {
        [self processFailedAuthorization:authStatus];
        [locationManager stopUpdatingHeading];
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        sender.on = FALSE;

    }
```

It seems that authStatus is sometimes showing as `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` despite having just prompted the user for authorisation.

I've stepped through the code in a debugger and it seems that if I wait for a small period of time before checking `CLAuthorizationStatus` then it does come back as authorised, whereas if I check immediately then it does not.

I know I could just wait for a second or so and then carry on, but there is nothing in the documentation about a delay being required.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CLLocationManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CLLocationManagerDelegate) has a callback, [locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidChangeAuthorizationStatus%3a), to let you know when the authorization status changes.  It passes the new status to your delegate.  That's the status to look at.  Just like location, the status in the CLLocationManager object can change.

Comment: So the thing to do would be to store the status in an iVar, implement the callback to update the iVar and check the iVar instead for permission?

Comment: No, checking an ivar isn't any different from what you are doing now. The thing to do is handle the change in the callback method.  Whatever you're going to do when the value changes, do that in the callback method.